# List AD Group Members With PHP and LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am attempting to list group members for groups in a certain OU in Active Directory using PHP and LDAP. For the most part this works but if a user is from another domain, it won't pick up on them. Below is the most basic attempt I have tried. I have tried other code examples as well. With debugging turned on to 7, I see it binding to say the Asia domain and I can see the DN of the user in the error_log but it doesn't return in php.

```
<?php
//LDAP server address
$LDAP_Server = "ldap://americas.ad.company.com";
//AD User to use
$LDAP_User = "username@americas.ad.company.com";
//AD User Password
$LDAP_Password = "Password";
//FQDN path where search will be performed. OU - organizational unit / DC - domain component
$LDAP_DN = "OU=SITE,OU=US,DC=americas,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com";
$LDAP_Search_String = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=SITE-UG-Group-M,OU=FileServer,OU=Groups,OU=SITE,OU=US,DC=americas,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com))";
// connecting to LDAP server
$LDAP_Connection = ldap_connect($LDAP_Server);
$LDAP_Bind = ldap_bind($LDAP_Connection, $LDAP_User , $LDAP_Password);
ldap_set_option($LDAP_Connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($LDAP_Connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
// performing search
$LDAP_Search = ldap_search($LDAP_Connection, $LDAP_DN, $LDAP_Search_String);
// Sort the results based on description
ldap_sort($LDAP_Connection, $LDAP_Search, 'samaccountname');

$LDAP_Data = ldap_get_entries($LDAP_Connection, $LDAP_Search);

echo "Found " . $LDAP_Data["count"] . " members<br><br>";

for ($i=0; $i<$LDAP_Data["count"]; $i++) {
    echo $LDAP_Data[$i]["dn"] . "<br>" . $LDAP_Data[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't really understand where PHP "doesn't return" the username. Do you see the users in the error log? can you show us an excerpt of that?. And 2 little things: 1st: You shoulkd call the ```set_option``` between the connect and the bind, not after the bind. 2nd: ldap_sort is deprecated as it only sorts on the client side and not on the server side so it might not be what you want.

Comment: The basic example above only returns users in say our Americas domain. If I use PowerShell or VBscript it returns all users.

Comment: Have you tried setting LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS to ```true```?